How to receive file data on binary with Lambda Power Tools?
I want to upload a file to S3 with the put_object method of Boto3, I want to receive the file via an http request with the binary body of the file.
    @app.post("/ref-arch/documents/<path>")
    @tracer.capture_method
    def documents(path:str) -> bool:
        
        data = app.current_event.body or "None"

        file_bin =  data.encode()
        
        result = asyncio.run(
            document_service.putObjectToS3Bytes(path=f"pruebas/documentos/{path}",data=file_bin)
        )
        return result

When receiving it in lambda and accessing the body it is in string format, is there any way to access this information in a binary way?
